# How to build a json object with a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to loop through a number of items, and create a json object. Each loop should be a new item on the object, but I'm having some issues doing it. It seems that only one set of items gets added, instead of multiple ones.

Here is my code:

```
jsonObj = {}
rows.each(function (index) {
    jsonObj["id"] = $this.find('.elementOne').val();
    jsonObj["name"] = $this.find('.elementTwo').text();

});
```

Here is what my json looks like:

```
{
    id: "3"
    name: "Stuff"
},
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
{
    id: "1"
    name: "Stuff"
},
{
    id: "2"
    name: "Stuff"
},
{
    id: "3"
    name: "Stuff"
}
```

Comment: Technically there is no such thing as a "JSON object" - JSON is a _string_ representing a _JavaScript Object_. What you are dealing with here is a _JavaScript Object_, not JSON.

Comment: JSON is a string representing a data structure which can be parsed with many programming languages. It is based on a subset of JavaScript, but the data types it supports appear in a great many languages.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no JSON here. Please don't confuse:

- A JavaScript object (a data structure)
- A JavaScript object literal (code to create such a data structure)
- JSON (a data format based on a subset of object literal notation)

If you want an ordered list of objects (or any other kind of JavaScript data structure) then use an array. Arrays have a `push` method.

```
var myData = [];
rows.each(function (index) {
    var obj = { 
        id: $this.find('.elementOne').val(),
        name: $this.find('.elementTwo').text()
    };
    myData.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You override the object instead of adding it a new value each iteration.

**Fixed code** using an array:

```
jsonObj = [];
rows.each(function(index) {
    jsonObj.push({
        'id': $this.find('.elementOne').val(),
        'name': $this.find('.elementTwo').text()
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want is an array of objects. When you try to write the same property on the same object multiple times, it gets overwritten which is why you're seeing `id` and `name` contain values for the last iteration of the loop.

Although you haven't tagged the question with jQuery, it does look like jQuery, so here's a solution:

I've taken the liberty to change `$this` to `this` because `$this` seems to be referring to the same object in each iteration, which is now what you may want (methinks)

```
var myArray = rows.map(function() {
    return {
        id: $(this).find('.elementOne').val(),
        name: $(this).find('.elementTwo').text()
    };
});
```

Comment: The best answer here. Nice N clean! +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this with jquery. The function will expect form elements of type input. It will iterate over thr passed form and it will collect each input name and value and it will create a json object like

Exmple:

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="I am value of field 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="I am value of field 2"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function buildObject(form) {
            var jsonObject = [],
                tempObj = {};
            $(form).find("input:not(input[type='submit'])").each(function() {
                tempObj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
            });

            jsonObject.push(tempObj);

            return jsonObject[0];
    }
    buildObject($("#myForm"));
    //Will produce

     jsonObj = {
        field1 : "I am value of field 1",
        field2 : "I am value of field 2"    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're merely overwriting the same properties of your object, `id` and `name`, each time. You need to be making a sub-object for each, then push it into the master object (which I've converted to array, since it's non-associative).

```
var jsonObj = []
rows.each(function (index) {
    var temp_obj = {};
    temp_obj["id"] = $this.find('.elementOne').val();
    temp_obj["name"] = $this.find('.elementTwo').text();
    jsonObj.push(temp_obj);
});
```

[EDIT] - as Mark Eirich's answer shows, the `temp_obj` is unnecessary - you could push an anonymous object instead, but I defined `temp_obj` just to make it crystal clear what's happening.

Also read Quentin's very good points re: common confusion between JavaScript objects and JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonObj = [];
rows.each(function(index) {
    jsonObj.push({
        id: $this.find('.elementOne').val(),
        name: $this.find('.elementTwo').text()
    });
});
```