# Get data added with jQuery from HTML table ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have some tables in my page. The data is added dynamically with jQuery.
This is working fine
Now I need to get all this data, cell by cell, wich were added by jquery, and send it to my controller as a model to insert into my DB.
This is my view:

```
@model prjArqBuild.entidade_endereco
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#endereco">
                    Endereços
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="endereco" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table" id="tabEndereco">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Endereco
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Numero
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Complemento
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Bairro
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Cidade
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                UF
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                CEP
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <p class="panel-title">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEndereco">
                        Adicionar Endereço
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEndereco" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Endereço</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <fieldset id="infoEndereco">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Endereço" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Numero" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_comple, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Complemento" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_comple, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Bairro" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_bairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Cidade" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_uf, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Estado" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_uf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "CEP" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    <button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="gravarDetalheEnd();" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery Function that add the data to the HTML table:

```
  function gravarDetalheEnd() {
            $('#tabEndereco tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + $('#een_endereco').val() + '</td><td>' + $('#een_numero').val() + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + $('#een_comple').val() + '</td>' + '<td>' + $('#een_bairro').val() + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + $('#een_cidade').val() + '</td>' + '<td>' + $('#een_uf').val() + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + $('#een_cep').val() + '</td></tr>');          
        }
```

I need to get all the cells and pass it to this Controller Action as EntEnd:

```
public void AddEndereco(entidade_endereco entEnd)
        {
            db.entidade_endereco.Add(entEnd);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I've tried a lot of thing, but nothing worked! I had no results!
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest serialising the data you want to store in the DB as JSON and use jQuery to AJAX POST it to your controller action. Something like:

```
var json = {
            entidade_endereco : {
//TODO: structure as per your model
            }
        }


$.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/AddEndereco",
                type: "POST",
                data: json,
                success: function (data) {
//TODO: success message or something
                }
```

Comment: sorry, I've never done this? Can you give me some more details? for note: I'm using MySQL 5.1

Comment: you need a jQuery foreach loop to iterate through your data to build up the JSON

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278161/how-to-build-a-json-object-with-a-loop

Comment: then submit the json with ajax POST as example above